# Select con campos vacios cuando no encuentra

Tags: sql

Suponiendo que tengo estas dos tablas con los siguientes registros

```
cliente
id      nombre
1       c1
2       c2
3       c3
4       c4 
5       c5

tabla2
id_cli   dato
1        d1
3        d3
10       d10
```

Si se hace esta selección nos muestra los clientes que están en tabla2

```
SELECT tabla2.*, cliente.nombre 
FROM cliente,tabla2
WHERE id = id_cli

id_cli   dato    nombre
1         d1       c1
3         d3       c3
```

pero lo que busco es que me muestre el siguiente resultado

```
id_cli   dato    nombre
1         d1       c1
3         d3       c3
10        d10
```

Que me muestre la tabla2 y si la id coincide que muestre el campo nombre

¿Es esto posible en sql? o lo tengo que hacer por codigo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es un `LEFT JOIN`, donde se muestran los campos coincidentes, y los no coincidentes de la tabla izquierda. Tal como se explica en el [manual de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
SELECT tabla2.id_cli, tabla2.dato, cliente.nombre 
FROM tabla2 
LEFT JOIN cliente ON tabla2.id_cli = cliente.id
```

Deberia funcionar. Puntualizar que los campos de cliente que no coincidan, seran mostrados como `NULL`.

Remitete a esta imagen para ver como funcionan los distintos tipos de `JOIN` graficamente.
 [image: Graficos JOIN]

#### Actualizacion

Es posible conseguir que efectivamente los campos `NULL` sean mostrados en blanco, tal como tu deseas. No es especialmente eficiente, pero hace lo que quieres. El codigo es para `MySQL`. En `MS SQL`, la funcion `IfNull` se cambia por `IsNull`, tal como se explica en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12394605/6062167).

```
SELECT tabla2.id_cli, tabla2.dato, IfNull(cliente.nombre, '') as nombre 
FROM tabla2 
LEFT JOIN cliente ON tabla2.id_cli = cliente.id
```

Comment: creo que deberias colocar donde sacastes esta informacion

Comment: @JackNavaRow Hecho :)